# Underpants in a Drawer

Tags: probability

I have 22 underpants in the drawer and it is dark and I cannot identify the colors. 3 pairs are red.

What is the probability of my putting on a red pair of underpants from the drawer?

3/22 is the wrong answer.

Comment: 3/11? What do you mean by 3 *pairs?* Is that 6 or 3 individuals?

Comment: *Why they are called pairs even though they are singles?* itself is much discussed question :-)

Comment: @Techidiot "And pants (pantaloons) were originally two like things. You put them on one leg at a time because they actually came in two pieces. You put on one leg, tied it around your waist, then put on the other. From the beginning, about the 16th Century, pants have been referred to as a pair."

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> 100%. You put on 20 pairs of underpants. With only two left you must be wearing a pair of red underpants.

Comment: But you put on **a** pair of underpants, singular, not plural

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil If he put on all pairs of underpants, he did, indeed, put on a pair of red underpants.

Comment: This is the clever answer  I used to give people, but strictly speaking there is a more detailed answer that is even more correct.

Comment: @BenRichards hmm I suppose so

Answer (score 3):

X*Y/Z, where X is the probability that you put on a pair of underpants from the drawer in the first place, Y is the total number of red underpants, which is at least 3, and Z is the total number of underpants of any color, which is at least 22.

Comment: closer to the correct answer.

Comment: Total number of red pants is explicitly mentioned to be 3 pairs. How do you get at least 3?

Comment: Given the close-to-correctness of my previous answer, the statement "3 pairs are red" could be interpreted loosely to be correct even if more than 3 pairs are red.

Answer (score 2):

3/11, because you have "22 underpants", meaning "11 *pairs* of underpants".

Comment: Pair is just a reference, as in pair of jeans. That means 1 article of clothing, not two in that sense. Unless it's a trick question

Comment: @n_palum: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

> Zero percent probability

because

> in the dark (with no light), all of them are black.

Comment: Something doesn't change colour because its dark, it just looks a different colour

Comment: 3/22 would be statistically correct. So I could only imagine that it was a trick question. Therefore, as color is simply determined by how light reflects off of the object, and if there is no light, they're effectively black. That's my reasoning.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil May be that is non lateral way of thinking(as the site is puzzling itself). We can't deny that

Answer (score 0):

Here is another try.

We have 22 underpants of which 3 are red - but maybe more.
If there could be any number of red underpants, we would have 20 scenarios:

---

1. 3 red / 19 non-red
2. 4 red / 18 non-red
3. 5 red / 17 non-red
4. 6 red / 16 non-red
5. 7 red / 15 non-red
6. 8 red / 14 non-red
7. 9 red / 13 non-red
8. 10 red / 12 non-red
9. 11 red / 11 non-red
10. 12 red / 10 non-red
11. 13 red / 9 non-red
12. 14 red / 8 non-red
13. 15 red / 7 non-red
14. 16 red / 6 non-red
15. 17 red / 5 non-red
16. 18 red / 4 non-red
17. 19 red / 3 non-red
18. 20 red / 2 non-red
19. 21 red / 1 non-red
20. 22 red / 0 non-red

---

Total number of possibilities in all scenarios:
250 red /190 non-red

---

As far as we know, we could be in any of the 20 scenarios picking any of the 22 underpants, so we have 20 * 22 = 440 different possibilities. Since 250 of the possibilities gives us a red pair of underpants, we get the answer:

250/440 = 25/44 = 57%